# SQLite :select where currend date between from date and to date if exist

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a db with records that have a fromDate and toDate field.

For getting the active record i use :
   
      `datetime('now') between fromDate and toDate;`

That works fine.

The thing is that the fields are not always populated.

I want that if the is no fromDate and no toDate i will always receive the record

If there is only a fromDate then after that date i will always receive the record I

If ther is only a toDate i will receive the record only until the toDate.

Thanks a lot

Avi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use logic like this:

```
where datetime('now') >= coalesce(fromDate, datetime('now'))
      datetime('now') <= coalesce(toDate, datetime('now'))
```

I don't recommend using `between` for date/time values.  Time components can sometimes produce unexpected results.